# Android How to get Artist Art (photo)

Tags: java, android

I have music player and I know how to pull the album art for an album given an album id.

```
content://media/external/audio/albumart
```

However, I can't find a way to fetch the image for an artist given using artist id and name.

Comment: no its not. The other thread shows how to pull the album art from an album id. I want to pull the musican's photo, not the album art.

Comment: As I know each music track has only one embedded albumart image within and is not necessarily artist picture, right?

Comment: Yah, I can get the track album art too, each track will just show the album art. However, I have a list of artist that I want to show their images. I've seen some music player that shows the artist photo along the artist, so I'm trying to pull that too.

Comment: @Julia did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API, you need to register and obtain an API key but ...

http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html#images

Comment: Is there anyway to do it within the android platform?

Comment: Yes you can do it, just launch an AsyncTask to the related endpoint of this API and in the returned json you have the img url.

Comment: Yah, but I don't want to rely on this API since if something goes wrong with this site, my app will crash.